# I need recommendation for structure to use Cytoscape js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

We are using Cytoscape + neo4j + spring boot + REST. We've tried to use some formats pass to frontend, however didn't work that well. So looking for best structure to use Cytoscape js.

========
Added later.
For example response from neo4j apoc export json query would be like this:

```
{
      "application": {
        "type": "node",
        "id": "hhj354",
        "labels": [
          "Application"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "appid": "A90378",
          "name": "hkjgj",
          "status": "In Production"
        }
      },
      "changes": [
        {
          "node": {
            "type": "node",
            "id": "fdsf324",
            "labels": [
              "Change"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "type": "gjhk",
              "startdate": "2019-11-21 02:11:32"
            }
          },
          "group": "2019-11",
          "relation": sfd
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "type": "node",
            "id": "fdsf324",
            "labels": [
              "Change"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "type": "gjhk",
              "startdate": "2019-11-21 02:11:32"
            }
          },
          "group": "2019-11",
          "relation": sfd
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "type": "node",
            "id": "fdsf324",
            "labels": [
              "Change"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "type": "gjhk",
              "startdate": "2019-11-21 02:11:32"
            }
          },
          "group": "2019-11",
          "relation": 453
        }
      ]
    }
```

I need some detailed parsing codes. Parsing in backend or front end both ok as long as short enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to include more details about your question, code, error messages and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, the front-end should do the less calculations as possible.
Therefore, try to send a JSON as close as possible to the **format** specified in the specs of [cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/specifying-basic-options)

The basic idea of graph is that it's composed of **nodes** and **edges**, those **elements** (as cytoscape calls them) have **ids** that can help you select them in a easier way.

**No Calculation in Back-End**

If you want to use built-in format .json from `CALL apoc.export.json.all("all.json",{useTypes:true})`then you will have for example to do some transformation in the front-end:

```
responseJson => {
    responseJson.map(element => {
        return {
        group: element.type,
        data : {
            id: `${element.type}${element.id}`,
            myFavouriteProperty: element.property
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't want to format in backend codes, so want to use apoc.export method in Neo4j. Did you use apoc export functions?

Comment: Then if I were you I would use CALL apoc.export.json.all("all.json",{useTypes:true} that would dump a json file. After looking at the docs of Neo4J, the .json is very close to the one expected by Cytoscape JS.

Comment: I was trying to use apoc.export.json.query(), because it's not for a whole database.